# How do you collapse multiple rows based on multiple columns in r?

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

So basically I have a dataframe that kinda looks like this:

```
Community Pop_Total Median_Age Under_5 5-9 10-14 15-19 20-24 
Akutan city   NA    NA         NA      NA  NA    NA    71
Alcan Border  NA    NA         2       NA  NA    NA    NA               
Alcan Border  NA    NA         NA      NA  NA    2     NA            
Alcan Border  NA    NA         NA      NA  5     NA    NA
Ambler City   224   NA         NA      NA  NA    NA    NA
Ambler City   NA    NA         NA      17  NA    NA    NA
```

Is there a simple way to combine multiple rows based on multiple column data? I've seen a few scripts that say you can combine one duplicate variable in a column based on one or two data columns but I need to do it more large scale (I have ~400 rows with duplicates and ~30 columns (and each column has a large name).

Ideally it would look like:

```
Community Pop_Total Median_Age Under_5 5-9 10-14 15-19 20-24 
Akutan city   NA    NA         NA      NA  NA    NA    71              
Alcan Border  NA    NA         2       NA  5     2     NA            
Ambler City   224   NA         NA      17  NA    NA    NA
```

I'm very new at R. Thank you!

Edit - I used the following code however a lot of column data (the data in rows after the first duplicate community name disappeared ex: the Alcon border values for 10-14 and 15-19 became NA) went missing when I collapsed it. Ideas?

```
library(dplyr)
census8 <- census7 %>%
  group_by(Community) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061), sharing some sample data in a copy/pasteable way. Since you tried to use `sum` it seems likely that your data is numeric (not `x`), so your example should reflect that.

Comment: Sure! I will edit it now with the first few columns of my dataset.

Comment: @Gregor It has been edited with actual data

Comment: But not copy/pasteable data :(

Comment: That said, now that we can see it, try adding `na.rm = TRUE` to your `summarise_each`. Should work.

Comment: @Gregor thank you! It almost worked, but it turned all of my NA into 0s, which is a bit of a problem further down the datatable since 0 is a value for some of them (but thats ok!)

Comment: You can also try using the aggregate() function. Read the documentation ahead of time for it, as it should give you some options to work with NAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the `NA`s in there the way you want you could use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA_integer_, sum(x, na.rm = T))), 
    by = Community]

#      Community Pop_Total Median_Age Under_5 5-9 10-14 15-19 20-24
#1:  Akutan_city        NA         NA      NA  NA    NA    NA    71
#2: Alcan_Border        NA         NA       2  NA     5     2    NA
#3:  Ambler_City       224         NA      NA  17    NA    NA    NA
```